# Is there a way to yield to variable section in statamic?

Tags: statamic

I have a layout with several identical columns which should yield to respective sections:

```
<div class="column_1">
  some column content here
  {{ yield:column_1 }}
  some more column stuff
</div>
<div class="column_2">
  some column content here
  {{ yield:column_2 }}
  some more column stuff
</div>
...
```

Now I would like to put that into its own partial:

```
******  LAYOUT  ******
  {{ partial:column column_name="column_1" }}
  {{ partial:column column_name="column_2" }}
  ...

******  PARTIALS/COLUMN.HTML  ******
  <div class="{{ column_name }}">
    some column content here
    {{ yield to-section="{column_name}" }}
    some more column stuff
  </div>


******  TEMPLATE    *****
  {{ section:column_1 }} **Additional stuff for column 1** {{ /section:column_1 }}
  {{ section:column_2 }} **Additional stuff for column 2** {{ /section:column_2 }}
```

But in the documentation I can only find the colon syntax `{{ yield:section }}` and no hint to a possible variable syntax `{{ yield unknown_word_here="section" }}`. Most tags have a variable syntax, so I am hoping there is one. Or another solution...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [Section](https://docs.statamic.com/tags/section) tag, which pairs nicely with the Yield tag.

Comment: Thats right. As I wrote: I want to YIELD to SECTIONS. But since every column looks the same, I want to use PARTIALS. the same for every column - except the YIELD part. That should YIELD to the SECTION with the respective column name. I clarified that. in the question. ... and of course I have a LAYOUT where I want to yield.... corrected that too